# issue with get array values outside the function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have created an array which will store dynamic values coming from DB. When I print the array  inside the transaction function it is printing. when I tried to print out side I didn't get the values. I have declared the array globally. what is the problem, my code is as follows;

```
function sendCategoryDetails() {

    var selected_category = $('#select-choice :selected').val();
    alert("control : " + selected_category);
    var mycoodinatesDetails;
    var myLocation = new Array();
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});

    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select Location from Locationlog WHERE Category = '"+selected_category+"';", [], 
            function (tx, res) {
                for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                    myLocation[i] = res.rows.item(i).Location;
                }
                alert (myLocation +" length : "+ myLocation.length); // Values are printing 
            });
    });
    alert (myLocation +" length : "+ myLocation.length); // values are not getting, It showing the length is 0
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to the world of Async calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tx.executeSql` is an async function. The `alert` works within the function since that is the *callback* and the async processing has finished. The `alert` after the function is trigger before the function has finished, thus being `undefined`.

Solution: Do the work inside the callback or call another function with the array passed as a parameter and do the work there.

Comment: Is it possible to write tx.executeSql inside another tx.executeSql ? I ant to write query for array elements. How can I do that ?

Comment: You can write another `execute` within the callback.